# Redirect a set of pages with .php extension to a subdomain with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have a bunch of PHP pages with a .php extension that live on an archived website moved to a subdomain, say old.example.com.

I want to redirect requests for this set of pages (PHP scripts) from the new website (example.com) to the archived website (old.example.com).

For example, if a GET request comes to the new website (example.com) for foo_bar.php or abc_abc.php or xyz_xyz.php, i want to redirect it (not a transparent redirect) with its full query string to the archived website (old.example.com), i.e.:

```
https://example.com/foo_bar.php?a=1&b=2
>
https://old.example.com/foo_bar.php?a=1&b=2
```

How can i do that with htaccess if i want to use **OR** clause between the targets with .php extension that should trigger the redirect rule and the number of targets isn't fixed (more can be added in the future)?

Comment: Also covered by: "[Mod_rewrite: Include query string when redirecting](//stackoverflow.com/q/4836355/90527)"

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(foo_bar\.php|abc_abc\.php|xyz_xyz\.php)$ https://old.example.com/$1 [R=302,NC]
```